# close vote review filter not working?

Tags: bug, review-queues, vote-to-close, review-audits

I am reviewing close votes with filter [matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/matlab) and only duplicate.
However I recently was asked to review [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/4953066) with a close reason "primarily opinion-based?"

What's wrong with my "duplicate" filter?

Comment: It appears to be an *audit* to make sure that you're paying attention as you review. But that doesn't make it less of a bug: audits shouldn't be so easy to spot!

Comment: @CodyGray well, seems like I was paying attention... to the filter at least...

Comment: @Shai I proposed a dupe target following an [example from MSE](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/204639/165773 "Audits bug in the filtered review queue") which also speaks about tag filters but appears to serve as dupe target for questions involving reason filters as well